# Catch different Sharepoint GUIDs

Tags: xml, powershell, api, sharepoint, office365

I coded a program which is mapping a specific list from a SP (O365) on my computer. 
To realize this, i'm using different GUID **(web, list, site)**.

I'm searching to catch all GUIDs that I need without doing myself. (_api/web after the url)

Do you have an idea ? Thanks a lot

```
param(
[string]$siteid='GUID',
[string]$webid='GUID',
[string]$URL='https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/group/',
[string]$listid='GUID',
[string]$webtitle='company'
)

$rand = Get-Random -Maximum 10
sleep $rand
#Sleep is required, if the same script runs at the same time it'll mess up the configuration.
$Version = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name ReleaseID | Select-Object ReleaseID
if($version.releaseID -lt 1709) { break }

$strFilter = “(&(objectCategory=User)(SAMAccountName=$Env:USERNAME))”
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = “Subtree”
$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(“userprincipalname”) | Out-Null
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll

$UPN =  (Get-ItemProperty -Path “HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\CloudDomainJoin\JoinInfo\*”).UserEmail
$path = "C:\Users\$($env:username)\Lime Networks BV\Lime Networks - $($listtitle)"
if(Test-Path $path){
#DoNothing
} else {
start "odopen://sync/?siteId=$siteid&webId=$webid&listId=$listid&userEmail=$upn&webUrl=$URL&webtitle=$webtitle&listtitle=$listtitle" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the required SharePoint list.
go to your list settings then

Copy the Url from the browser address bar into Notepad. It will look something like:
(https://yoursharepointintranet/yoursite/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7B26534EF9%2DAB3A%2D46E0%2DAE56%2DEFF168BE562F%7D)

Delete everying before the first percentage character from "List=" back to "https".
Change “%7B” to “{”
Change all “%2D” to “-“
Chnage “%7D” to “}”
You are now left with the Id:

{26534EF9-AB3A-46E0-AE56-EFF168BE562F}
and that is your GUID.